# Help proving honeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology

Is the following true:
$$S^n-S^0\cong S^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}$$
How to prove it simply?
Is there a formula for $S^n-S^r$, $0\leq r\leq n$?

Comment: What does $S^0$ stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $S^{0}\cong \{1,-1\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}.$

[Stereographic projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) give an homeomorphism of $S^n-\{P\}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since $\mathbb{R}^n-\{Q\}$ and $S^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphic ( for any $Q \in \mathbb{R}^n$)we get that
$$S^n-S^0\cong S^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}.$$

One homeomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\} \to S^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}$ is 
$f(X)=(\frac{X}{\|X\|},\ln{(\|X\|)}).$